# About meniscus of combination of fluids

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

- 1st Question. Let us say we have a beaker(glass tube) of half filled water. Surely the surface of water attains a curved shape. Will this shape remain if oil is added on top of water?
- 2nd question. Will there be existence of meniscus in the following situation:

  A barometer is taken filled with water completely and inverted in a cup of water. Note that no air is allowed in the tube.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for the first question, we know meniscus forms due to the adhesive and cohesive force acting between the material in which it is kept and the liquid itself, so even if we add oil in water there should still be a meniscus, but shape could vary.
And yeah as from the first answer it is due to the adhesive and cohesive forces so, it should still remain.

DISCLAIMER: Don't take this as the final answer wait for the other answers.(I am pretty sure that the meniscus is due to the a and c forces) because according to what I am taught in my grade 11(currently in grade 12) this is my answer, but the others who answer please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you considering the a and c forces between oil and water?

Comment: Adhesive force acts between different materials , so like there will be adhesive force due to glass, oil with water and cohesive is the one which substance has with itself so like interaction between the water molecules. Yeah we'll consider that but I don't know what will be the shape of meniscus after oil is added because it depends upon how much force will be there.

Comment: So you do know right that why was there a meniscus in the first place, right?

Comment: And yeah if you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it correct and if not you can ask me more questions.

Comment: I am currently in 11th. So how would you predict the shape considering the an and c forces. Also the contact angle

Comment: Okay, so like if you see just a simple water in a glass beaker then what happens is that all water molecules attracts the water molecule just touching the glass so like the average cohesive force would be at 45° with the horizontal and glass just attracts the water molecule horizontally now if horizontal component of cohesive force is greater than adhesive force then the meniscus would be inwards and if the opposite meniscus would be bulging outwards, similarly when oil is added then we will need to see how are the forces acting and accordingly decide the shape that would be little difficult.

Comment: If I could add an image you would understand better but I don't know how to do that, but the point is we take components of force and shape would be decided in what direction is net force acting.